# MySQL Duplicate a database

Tags: mysql

I want to copy (all data, schema, procedures and so on) from database1 to database2, that are located on the same server. 
I've tried using mysqldump but each time I get

> ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 18: Access denied; you need (at least one
>   of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

That because my root user that I use for this operation does not have SUPER privilege and I don't have access to change this.

**Is there a solution to do this without using mysqldump?**

Keep in mind that it's a pretty big database with over one hundred tables.

Answer (score 2):

You have to grant privilegies to the user:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'username'@'yourhost';
```

if you want to do it for all databases:

```
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'username'@'yourhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to copy the two databases without `mysqldump`, not to grant privileges to root user. I don't have access to give SUPER access to root user.

Comment: @AlexChihaia but using this answer, you can grant the SUPER privilege to the user and the you can do what you need to do.

Comment: @Martin has a point here, maybe I'm a little lost in what you are trying to do, but I don't see why this is not enaugh :/...

Comment: @AlexChihaia I made a little research for you, maybe make a back up and restore it is a way to do it, see here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64630/sql-server-2012-copy-database-failed . Please let me know if that worked for you

Comment: @Martin as I said before, I don't have the access rights to give all privileges to root user.

Comment: @AlexChihaia I misunderstand your issue, if your user *doesn't* have SUPER prilvege then are you sure your user is **root**? I would expect that the root MySQL user would have the highest level of access, by its very nature. Please bear in mind that if you login via an interface such as "CPanel* etc. that just because you log in to *that interface* as "root", does not automatically mean the MySQL used by the interface is also root.